# Possible to upgrate SQL Server 2012 express to 2012 Standard?

Tags: sql-server

I need to do an in place upgrade of SQL server 2012 express to standard without losing any data. Is this possible? Is it as simple as just running the setup for the standard version? TIA

Comment: [Supported Version and Edition Upgrades](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393(v=sql.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible and very simple :

- First you have to launch the "Installation Center SQL Server" app.
- Secondly, go to the panel "Maintenance"
- Third click on "upgrade edition"
- And finally follow the steps.

Hope this helps you

EDIT : i don't see that an other man answer before me

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's as simple as running the setup and execute the edition upgrade.

Just in case it's better to backup your database before but everything should be ok.

Details here : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707783.aspx

Of course, you should buy the standard licence.